# Reading from a log file in node js

Tags: node.js

I need to read from a log file already consisting of data and wait for future events which are dynamically updated to the file.
I couldn't use '**text-file-follower**' since it did not read the already existing contents. Also, I need to reload the file when i detect log rotation.

Is there any package in **nodejs** that performs all of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly use this: It parse large files line by line using a stream & pipe.

```
var fs = require('fs')
    , util = require('util')
    , stream = require('stream')
    , es = require('event-stream');

var lineNr = 0;

var s = fs.createReadStream('very-large-file.csv')
    .pipe(es.split())
    .pipe(es.mapSync(function(line){

        // pause the readstream
        s.pause();

        lineNr += 1;

        // process line here and call s.resume() when rdy
        // function below was for logging memory usage
        logMemoryUsage(lineNr);

        // resume the readstream, possibly from a callback
        s.resume();
    })
    .on('error', function(err){
        console.log('Error while reading file.', err);
    })
    .on('end', function(){
        console.log('Read entire file.')
    })
);
```

Hope it helps

Thanks

Comment: This didn't wait for any new events. I used to following code by using the Tail package which worked:

`const filepath = "path/to/file";
var Tail = require('tail').Tail;
var options = {fromBeginning: true};
var tail = new Tail(filepath, options);

tail.on('line', function(data) {
 //do something with data
 
});

tail.on("error", function(error) {
    console.log('ERROR: ', error);
});`

In the log file, if I want to start processing from a specific line, say from line 100 to EOF, I am not able to do this with the code. Does Tail provide any such options?

Comment: try wait:
 (function wait () {
   if (!SOME_EXIT_CONDITION) setTimeout(wait, 1000);
})();